# Svelte+TS type declaration inside a HTML tag attribute

Tags: html, typescript, svelte, unexpected-token

Sooo. This works cause the types in TS are implicitly any.

```
<button on:click={() => {let modal; ...}></button>
```

But if I want to specify it like this:

```
<button on:click={() => {let modal:any; ...}></button>
```

it throws me a "Unexpected tokents(-1)" error.

I expected it to not throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Svelte Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/typescript#limitations) list this as a limitation.

You haven't told us what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to use Typescript in your button click handler. You could write a function within the `<svelte lang="ts">` block, and reference it from your markup.

Comment: Well daisy ui has a weird way of toggeling the modal and I didn't want to use the script section to create a variable because I wanted it to be bundled up together so that I can easily copy and paste it and also for stylistic purposes. I mean the first code snippet works and it serves my needs it just throws me a "Variable 'modal' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7043)" suggestion. Anyways thanks for the quick reply